# Azure Media Services v3 - c# Odata Query fails with 400 Bad Request for properties.created gt date works for REST api

Tags: azure-media-services

Azure Media Services v3 - c# Odata Query fails with **400 Bad Request** for **properties.created gt date** works for REST api.

**Working REST Version**

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/ResGroup/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/testurstream/assets?api-version=2018-07-01&$filter=properties/created gt 2018-06-01 and properties/created lt 2019-07-01

**Broken .NET Version** (Fiddler trace)

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/ResGroup/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/testurstream/assets?$filter=properties/created%20gt%20'2018-11-11T10%3A48%3A37Z'&api-version=2018-07-01

Docs state greater than is supported for created.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/assets-concept#filtering-ordering-paging

`properties.created Supports: Eq, Gt, Lt    Supports: Ascending and Descending`

**Code Sample:**

```
var query = new ODataQuery<Asset>(item => item.Created > lastFetchTime);
var assets = _client.Assets.List(ResourceGroup, AccountName, query);
```

**Exception:**

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.ApiErrorException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
Source=Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media
StackTrace:
  at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.AssetsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.AssetsOperationsExtensions.<ListAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.AssetsOperationsExtensions.List(IAssetsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String accountName, ODataQuery`1 odataQuery)
```

Fiddler Result

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
13  400 HTTPS   management.azure.com    /subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/ResGroup/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/testurstream/assets?$filter=properties/created%20gt%20'2018-11-11T00%3A00%3A00Z'&api-version=2018-07-01 217 private application/json; charset=utf-8 amstestv3:7148
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .NET is quoting the string for the 8601 datetime, which is breaking the call.

I checked in Postman also and this works fine: 
$filter=properties/created gt 2018-01-11T01:00:00Z

But this quoted string throws a similar error message:
$filter=properties/created gt '2018-01-11T01:00:00Z'

Let me check on this with our .NET SDK team.

Answer (score 0):

Working version - format string directly.

```
if (lastFetchTime != null)
{
    var dateTime = lastFetchTime.GetValueOrDefault().ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
    var odataQuery = $"properties/created lt {dateTime}";
    query = new ODataQuery<Asset>(odataQuery);
}

var data = _client.Assets.List(ResourceGroup, AccountName, query);
```